# Ruby and Elasticsearch for mapping partial search property

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I'm working on an existing code written in Ruby (I guess it uses some Elasticsearch Gem).
The Elasticsearch version is 5.5.

This code works but I'm trying to understand what is going on in a specific part of the code, especially the 'do' after the 'name' in the second line.

```
mapping dynamic: false do
  indexes :title, type: 'text', analyzer: "name" do
    indexes :partial, type: 'text', analyzer: "autocomplete",
    search_analyzer: "autocomplete_search"
  end
end
```

- Does this mean 'title' property
  has a child field called 'partial'?
- Is it possible to translate this code to a curl API call?

Answer (score 0):

This code sets mapping rules for index that will be created from your Ruby code.

> Does this mean 'title' property has a child field called 'partial'?

No. It has same field but with different index. [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/multi-fields.html)

> Is it possible to translate this code to a curl API call?

Yes. I can show you partial solution (because you using some custom 'name' analyzer) that also must be in your code.

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "name",
        "fields": {
          "partial": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested your code but I got 'Mapping definition for [title] has unsupported parameters'. By changing "properties" to "fields" under "title" it worked! So does this means the 'do' keyword translates to 'fields' property?

Comment: Sorry for that, I was inattentive. You have not nested field in this case, but SAME field analyzed in different ways. I had edit my answer.